# Bash git list of still open pr

Tags: bash, git, github, ls-remote, git-ls-remote

Is there a command in bash using git that allows me given a repository, know all the pr that are open there?

For example, he finds me more open than those who actually exist.

Command:

```
git ls-remote https://github.com/CodeEditApp/CodeEdit "refs/pull/*/merge"
```

Result:

```
533479b407dc603fb8ad595e6688834431798dc2    refs/pull/1169/merge
08ad7a8157f1674328c91e52aac4353dce18a529    refs/pull/118/merge
641b0f15fada81e2f3630b4d398619ef019483d7    refs/pull/1283/merge
cc898565328db7c01b17a517a1cfcc281a0feaa4    refs/pull/1518/merge
c5b9937c302c2e12fb8d1299134107fa2fb95eba    refs/pull/1535/merge
cc2134231e38f8251f92a5c6225281708e3929c4    refs/pull/1564/merge
57ccf0f6f77675b4b29461fa5983d8bb502ab5cf    refs/pull/1581/merge
9f97254a83da70dded4951388c36533e3cfead4b    refs/pull/1582/merge
be8793adca5b0861499a944c09d7d2a4d7980395    refs/pull/237/merge
cc9103172621536c937f8b695598ccc5bcead1ce    refs/pull/25/merge
c97bf39388db2d5c2158b66944a1728eb6cef536    refs/pull/591/merge
1a99d22ef33478549468e35ae3c195cbf65054d3    refs/pull/673/merge
7118573f296045228c1993a25ea5156faf92c29b    refs/pull/690/merge
```

Can you give me a hand?

Comment: There are others that are included in that list by running that code, which are actually already closed or merged.

Comment: I didn't understand the link correctly, what code should it have?

Comment: I’m sorry. I embarrassingly shared the wrong link. :) [Correct link](https://gist.github.com/mtilson/be5e01de1182180b720adc3393a5cba1) That one says that `refs/pull/*/merge` “correspond to open pull requests only”.

Comment: It seems that this thing does not match see the pull 1169 is given as open but: https://github.com/CodeEditApp/CodeEdit/pull/1169

Comment: same thing for 118, 25, 591, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Pull requests are not a native concept in Git, so there's no built-in way to do this.

Since you've tagged this question with GitHub, though, the `gh` command-line tool (https://cli.github.com/) has this function already: `gh pr list --state open` will return a list of the ID, title, source branch, and relative creation date of all open PRs in a given repo.

Comment: I have a possible solution, I don't know if it works, to make an intersection between the following two commands:

cmd: `git ls-remote https://github.com/CodeEditApp/CodeEdit "refs/pull/*/head"`

cmd2: `git ls-remote https://github.com/CodeEditApp/CodeEdit "refs/pull/*/merge"`

Take the common parts, this way you can know which ones are open.

But I'm not succeeding.